# Minkowski's question mark function iterations

Tags: special-functions, irrational-numbers

[The Minkowski's question mark function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question_mark_function) (we use the sign $?$ to note this function) was designed in 1904 by Minkowski. It can be defined as an increasing bijection between $\mathbb Q$ and [the set of dyadic numbers $\mathbb D$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).

Surprisingly, it's also a bijection between [the set of quadratic algebraic numbers $\mathbb A_2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_irrational) and $\mathbb Q$.

So we have

- $?^{-1}(\mathbb D)=\mathbb Q$
- $?^{-2}(\mathbb D)=?^{-1}(\mathbb Q)=\mathbb A_2$

Are they any characterization of the sets $?^{z}(\mathbb D)$ for each $z\in\mathbb Z$ ?

What is $\displaystyle\mathbb R\setminus\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb Z}?^z(\mathbb D)$ ?

We have $?^z(\mathbb D)\subsetneq?^{(z-1)}(\mathbb D)$ (this is fun as $?$ is a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb D$ is dense in $\mathbb R$), so $\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb Z}?^z(\mathbb D)=\lim_{z\rightarrow -\infty}?^z(\mathbb D)$

---

EDIT :

This question did not get any attention. If this is a known open question, please let me know!

Comment: It should not be surprising that it maps quadratic surds to Q bijectively. The real surprise is that x has a periodic continued fraction representation iff x is a quadratic surd. From this, you can split the infinite series in the definition of ?(x) into several infinite geometric series which clearly sum to rationals. The size of the period tells you how many geometric series there will be.

Comment: @Daniel But do you have any idea of what it maps to quadratic algebraic numbers bijectively ?

Answer (score 2):

These are wide open questions due to the following reason.

One can calculate $?(x)$ explicitly only if one knows the continued fraction expansion of $x$. For example,

$$
?\Big{(}\frac{e-1}{e+1}\Big{)}=1-\theta_{4}\Big{(}0, \frac{1}{4}\Big{)},
$$
where $\theta_{4}$ is the Jacobi theta-function. Equally, one can calculate $?^{-1}(x)$ only if the binary expansion of $x$ is known.

What You are asking about $?^{-1}(\mathbb{A}_{2})$ can be asked differently: present an example of quadratic irrational whose binary expansion (or some of its non-trivial statistics like normality) is known. And this is a wide open problem (but note [this seminal paper](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2007/165-2/p04) by Boris Adamczewski and Yann Bugeaud).